# Glob file pattern excluding node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, karma-runner, glob

I am trying to setup a karma config file, and I am struggling creating a glob that matches my files

I have a lerna repository, which means that there could be some `node_modules` folders inside the packages, and I don't want them to be included in my test suite.

I have all my tests inside test folders, so the idea of the blob should be:

```
/packages/a/test/aa.test.js //should match
/packages/a/node_modules/b/test/aa.test.js  //shouldn't match
/packages/a/b/test/aa.test.js //should match
```

The goal is to match every `test/*.test.js` file in the folder tree, EXCEPT if any of the folders si named `node_modules`. Any ideas?

I though that something lke `/packages/(**|!(node_modules))/test/*.test.js` would work, but not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
/^(?!.*node_modules).\w+.*/gm
```

you can check it here: https://regexr.com/5aod6

Comment: Thank you, but I need it in glob format, not regex. You can check it here: https://globster.xyz/ with the paths that I provided