# Excluding a portion of filename with glob expression

Tags: glob

I'm having trouble excluding test files from my glob expression as follows :
I have this list of files

```
./app/tags.ts
./app/tag.ts
./app/status.ts
./app/bar/{foo}/baz.ts
./app/.hidden.ts
./app/_hidden.ts
./app/foo_dir/.hidden.ts
./app/some/testing_should_be_hidden.test.ts
```

I'm trying to exclude everything that starts with a '.' or starts with a '_' or includes a '.test' in the filename

so far this is what I tried :

[Glob file pattern excluding node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63559485/glob-file-pattern-excluding-node-modules)

with my expression :

```
./**/[!._]*^(?!*test).{ts,js}
```

but It didn't work, however using:

```
./**/[!._]*.{ts,js}
```

excludes the 'hidden' files but not the test one

FYI : test is available here :
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob?comments=false&glob=.%2F%2A%2A%2F%5B%21._%5D%2A%5E%28%3F%21%2Atest%29.%7Bts%2Cjs%7D&matches=false&tests=.%2Fapp%2Ftags.ts&tests=.%2Fapp%2Fgame%2F%7BgameId%7D%2Fclip.ts&tests=.%2Fapp%2F.hidden.ts&tests=.%2Fapp%2F_hidden.ts&tests=.%2Fapp%2Fgame%2F.hidden.ts&tests=.%2Fapp%2Fsome%2Ftesting.test.ts

Answer (score 0):

So far this worked for me :

```
./**/[!._]!(*.test).{ts,js}
```

Can anyone explain this to me vs :

```
./**/[!._]*!(*.test).{ts,js}
```